# Using tkinter to output text from sqlite3 database

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I have made a database and added some random details. I have pulled this data from the database and I need to output this in a Tkinter GUI window. When using the Label to output the contents I usually put text.

```
example = Label(self.frame, text='Example')
```

Is there something else I should use instead of a Label?

```
def create_records():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MemberRecordsTable(surname TEXT, 
    firstname TEXT, membertype TEXT, datejoined TEXT)')

def readrecords(self):
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM MemberRecordsTable') 
    for row in c.fetchall():
        memberprint2 = Label(self.frame, text = row)
def memberprint(self):
    self.clearframe()
    readrecords()
```

Answer (score 0):

You create one new label for each row.  Use a Text widget if you want all of the data in one container http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm .  Note that create_records() is missing a self, so is not part of the class like the other 2 functions,

```
text_w = Text(self.frame, height=20, width=10, wrap="none")
text_w.grid(row=0, column=0)

......

text_w.insert(END, any_string)
```